# Where is Soft Buttons on KitKat Emulator?

Tags: android

I have updated Android SDK to KitKat and created a KitKat emulator but I can't see any soft button in it. I tried to scroll bottom-up with no success. Do you know how can I see soft bottons? Is there any shortcut?[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see software (on-screen) keyboard you have to disable the "hardware keyboard present" in your AVD configuration.

Andrei.

Answer (score -1):

I think so you have not created the emulator perfectly My Friend

Look over the configuration and options Check it thorough