# Setting Up Android 4.4 kitkat emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to setup android kitkat 4.4 emulator using AVD manager. I see an option to choose API level but I dont see a compatible device under the device list. If i try using Nexus 10, the emulator runs but just doesnt display anything. So, while I was checking stackoverflow, I knew many people are running emulators like this one:

[Where is Soft Buttons on KitKat Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767399/where-is-soft-buttons-on-kitkat-emulator)

But whats the problem in mine? I did give it enough properties so that it would work fine(like VM space), but I know that Kitkat can work on memory constrained devices also (as seen in dev bytes on youtube), so I guess thats not a problem. In short how do I setup an emulator specifically for Android phones(not tablets) preferably for google nexus 5. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I set up my emulator like in the picture below and it works. Especially "Use Host GPU" option seems to help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents on this question, I've found that the following settings worked for me

- Internal storage to 200MiB
- RAM to 256
- Heap to 32

Same settings as above otherwise.