# Android Intel x86 Emulator KitKat (19) not starting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

I recently upgraded all my packages. Now I am on 4.4.2 19, with SDK Tools 22.6.1, Platform 19.0.1 and Intel Atom Image 19.2. I am working on Windows 7.

I can start Intel Emulator on 4.2 or 2.3 version in less than a minute.

If I start Intel Emulator on 4.4 (or 4.3) I get a blank screen (not even the Android boot logo).

I tried so far:

- Different devices and screen sizes
- Different memory options like suggested here
- Even low memory start (128 MB)
- With or without Host GPU usage
- removing all Device functionality like GPS, Accelerometer etc.
- Starting with -noaudio
- adb kill/start-server
- watched memory (6 GB installed, 2 GB on Stand-By, no difference to 4.2 start, so this does not seem an issue.)
- Uninstalling all Intel packages and re-installing.

(Most coming from [Emulator for Android 4.4 KitKat is not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051073))

When I start the emulator, HAX is working fine.

Using the emulator ... -debug-all option gives me the following last commands:

```
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: connection refused
emulator: ping program: C:\Users\gsc\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ddm
s.bat
emulator: ping command: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\gsc\AppData\Loc
al\Android\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat" ping emulator 22.6.1.0 "Intel" "Intel(R)
HD Graphics 4000" "4.0.0 - Build 9.18.10.3165"
```

(Note: the can't connect is the same for working 4.2 emulator, so this does not seem to be an issue.)

Missing next command is:

```
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:169: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_WRITE_BUFFER_1 007c0000
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_WRITE_BUFFER_2 007c4000
emulator: goldfish_audio_read: AUDIO_READ_SUPPORTED returns 1
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_READ_BUFFER 007c8000
```

Appreciate any more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, all of the mentioned things you've tried didn't work for me.

Updating Intel HAXM Accelerator from 1.0.1 to 1.0.8. did the trick for me (just google "intel haxm download")

Comment: Yup, did the trick! Thank you very much for this answer. SDK should auto-update this.

Comment: I installed Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager 6.0.3 over 6.0.1 -- not sure if this is the same thing you're talking about but it worked!

Comment: Well not exactly the same, but the same pattern. It seems like android SDK releases are bound to a minimum version of HAXM Accelerator. (Unfortunately, this info isn't published anywhere)